# qgis polygon to coordinates

Tags: qgis, polygon, google-maps, coordinates, ordnance-survey

I have the ordnance survey postcode polygons, i can get the centre point on the postcode (Using polygon centroids) and all the corner coordinates (using extract nodes)

Does anyone know how to export the coordinates of each postcode boundary to csv so it can be drawn on a google map?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click the layer in the Layers table of content and select *Save As*...
2. For the format drop down select *Comma Separated Value*, see caption below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, incase you hadnt guessed im new to this :P Is there any way to only export certain columns?

Comment: you could use "skip attribute creation" for the bare coordinates, but the best way is to delete not need columns in openoffice/excel .. btw: you can use save as kml also and import into google map

Answer (score 1):

The MMQGIS plugin allows you to export the geometry to a csv file which includes all coordinates of the polygon corners:

`MMQGIS -> Import/Export -> Geometry Export to CSV file`